# code looks great in codeacademy, but not any other browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ive been working on a 3d website, and i decided it would be easier to work on it through code academy make your own video game. https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-X7bpO/0/1

because it is quick and simple, and the result is immediate. So i got really invested the code started looking good, but when i took the code to any other code editor, it only displays a black screen. In code academy however, it displays a 3d room with a video screen tv. Why doesn't my code work?

This is my code. Go to code academy make your own video game and Copy and paste this code into the editor and it looks good. But anywhere else and i get a black screen. Any Ideas ?

[This is How The 3d site looks in code Academy make your own video game editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUgnR.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
   
    <style> 
    html,body { 
      min-height: 100%; 
      min-width: 100%; 
      background: black; 
    }
    .wrap {
 perspective: 99px;
 perspective-origin: center ;
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%; 
 background:black;
}
.cube {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%;
 top: 200px;
 left: 200px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out; 
}
.cube div {
 position: absolute;
   transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50%; 
    
    
}

.img { 
  position: absolute;   
 width: 100%;   
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px; 
 right: 0px; 
 
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out; 
 transform: tranalateZ(200px); 
 animation-name: myframes; 
  animation-duration: 6s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

.img1 { 
  position: absolute;   
 width: 100%;   
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px; 
 right: 0px; 
 
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out; 
 transform: tranalateZ(200px); 
 animation-name: myframes; 
  animation-duration: 6s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes myframes2 { 
 0% {
   transform: translateZ();   
 }

 100% {
   transform: translateZ(100px);   
 }
}


.cube:hover { 
    
}

@keyframes spin {
 from { transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { transform: rotateX(360deg); }
}




.back {
    
 transform: translateZ(-100px) ;
 background: black; 
 
  animation-name: myframes1; 
  animation-duration: 6s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

.p {
 position: absolute;    
}



.right {
 transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
 transform-origin: top right;
  background: black; 
   background-image: url("http://garagejazz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Wood-Wall-Paneling.jpg"); 
  background-size: 20px 100px; 
}

.left {
 transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
 transform-origin: center left;
  background: black; 
  background-image: url("http://garagejazz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Wood-Wall-Paneling.jpg"); 
  background-size: 20px 100px; 
  
}
.top {
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
 transform-origin: top center;
  background: black; 
   background-image: url("http://www.featurepics.com/StockImage/20080324/sprayed-ceiling-texture-stock-photo-663871.jpg"); ); 
   background-size: 20px 20px; 
   
}
.bottom {
 transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
 transform-origin: bottom center;
  background: black; 
  background-image: url("http://azmind.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/free-wood-background-set.jpg"); 
  
}




.front {
 transform: translateZ(100px);
  background: black; 
}


    
    
    
    
    </style> 
        <title></title>
        <link/>
        <script></script>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div class="wrap">
 <div class="cube">
  <div class="front">front</div>
  <div class="back">back
  <img class = 'img1'src = "http://ib1.huluim.com/show_key_art/1304?size=1600x600&region=US"> 
 <iframe class = 'img' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x4GZSwRt6OA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
 </div>
</div>
 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script> 

$('.img').hide(); 



setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.img1').fadeOut(1500); 
  $('.img').fadeIn(3000);   
},2000); 

</script> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by removing the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration, though this is not a preferable solution, as it indicates that a mistake was made in the style.

Instead, try adding the following to your style for `html, body`:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

You should then get the expected results outside of codecademy.

Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
   
    <style> 
    html,body { 
      min-height: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
      background: black; 
    }
    .wrap {
 perspective: 99px;
 perspective-origin: center ;
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%; 
 background:black;
}
.cube {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%;
 top: 200px;
 left: 200px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out; 
}
.cube div {
 position: absolute;
   transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50%; 
    
    
}

.img { 
  position: absolute;   
 width: 100%;   
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px; 
 right: 0px; 
 
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out; 
 transform: tranalateZ(200px); 
 animation-name: myframes; 
  animation-duration: 6s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

.img1 { 
  position: absolute;   
 width: 100%;   
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px; 
 right: 0px; 
 
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out; 
 transform: tranalateZ(200px); 
 animation-name: myframes; 
  animation-duration: 6s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes myframes2 { 
 0% {
   transform: translateZ();   
 }

 100% {
   transform: translateZ(100px);   
 }
}


.cube:hover { 
    
}

@keyframes spin {
 from { transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { transform: rotateX(360deg); }
}




.back {
    
 transform: translateZ(-100px) ;
 background: black; 
 
  animation-name: myframes1; 
  animation-duration: 6s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

.p {
 position: absolute;    
}



.right {
 transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
 transform-origin: top right;
  background: black; 
   background-image: url("http://garagejazz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Wood-Wall-Paneling.jpg"); 
  background-size: 20px 100px; 
}

.left {
 transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
 transform-origin: center left;
  background: black; 
  background-image: url("http://garagejazz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Wood-Wall-Paneling.jpg"); 
  background-size: 20px 100px; 
  
}
.top {
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
 transform-origin: top center;
  background: black; 
   background-image: url("http://www.featurepics.com/StockImage/20080324/sprayed-ceiling-texture-stock-photo-663871.jpg"); ); 
   background-size: 20px 20px; 
   
}
.bottom {
 transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
 transform-origin: bottom center;
  background: black; 
  background-image: url("http://azmind.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/free-wood-background-set.jpg"); 
  
}




.front {
 transform: translateZ(100px);
  background: black; 
}


    
    
    
    
    </style> 
        <title></title>
        <link/>
        <script></script>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div class="wrap">
 <div class="cube">
  <div class="front">front</div>
  <div class="back">back
  <img class = 'img1'src = "http://ib1.huluim.com/show_key_art/1304?size=1600x600&region=US"> 
 <iframe class = 'img' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x4GZSwRt6OA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
 </div>
</div>
 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script> 

$('.img').hide(); 



setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.img1').fadeOut(1500); 
  $('.img').fadeIn(3000);   
},2000); 

</script> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when I remove the Declaration at the top and I change min-height,min-width to height  and width. for some reason I can only see the back of the cube, which contains the video. The right,left,top, and bottom are blacked out

Comment: @jalenjackson Does the code snippet work for you expand it to full page?

Comment: Oh i got it ! i see what your saying here, thanks that clears up so much confusion from previous projects as well. Thanks so much man

Comment: @jalenjackson I'm glad to hear that it helped. If you feel the answer is correct, please consider accepting as the answer.